# Error in datetime query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datetime

I am using the following **sql**query in **asp.net** to **Group by** three tables using **inner join** :

```
  SELECT tblVendorItem.Name, 
  tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price AS 'Sale', 
  tblEventService.ServiceDate
  FROM tblEventService 
  INNER JOIN  tblEventItem ON 
  tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID 
  INNER JOIN  tblVendorItem ON 
  tblEventItem.VendorItemID = tblVendorItem.VendorItemID
  INNER JOIN  tblVendor ON 
  tblVendorItem.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
  WHERE (tblEventService.VendorID = 1) 
  AND (tblEventService.ServiceDate BETWEEN '20-04-2015 00:00:00' AND '23-04-2015 00:00:00')
  GROUP BY 
  tblVendorItem.Name, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price, tblEventService.ServiceDate
```

Here, *VendorID* and *Dates* are static. The query got parsed but on executing,it shows the following error:

[image: Image of the Error has been attached]

I have check the datatype in both,the **model** class and **table**, it shows *datetime*.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the query or how can this error can be solved?

Comment: in where condition :convert(VARCHAR(20),tblEventService.ServiceDate,103) BETWEEN (convert(VARCHAR(20),'20-04-2015 00:00:00',103) AND (convert(VARCHAR(20),'23-04-2015 00:00:00',103))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ISO standard formats for your constants:

```
tblEventService.ServiceDate BETWEEN '2015-04-20' AND '2015-04-23'
```

Also, the time components are unnecessary.

Also, I would recommend only using single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

If You want `Time` in your result and,looking at your query it seems you will need 3 parameters.`VendorID`,`FromDate` and`ToDate`. So Add below code in your method. `VendorID` you need to access differently..

```
 string startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTo.Text + " 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + " 00:00:00");
 string enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateFrom.Text + " 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + " 00:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add MM-DD-YYYY date
i.e.

```
> where mydatecol BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '04-20-2015 00:00:00') AND
> CONVERT(datetime, '04-20-2015 00:00:00')
```

Else you have to apply format specified for DD-MM-YYYY

```
> mydatecol BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '20-04-2015 00:00:00', 103) AND
> CONVERT(datetime, '20-04-2015 00:00:00', 103)
```